# Force Refresh the context.auth.token in firebase callable functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

My app works(or should work) like this:

1. The user registers through firebase authentication
2. He is prompted to verify his email, clicking in the link sent to it by the app
3. Then he clicks in a button that calls a firebase function, whose first block of code is this:

```
if (!context.auth.token.email_verified) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("failed-precondition",
    "User must verify its email.");
}
```

The problem is: **even after the user having confirmed its email, the function still throws this error. Only AFTER one or two minutes, the 'context.auth.token.email_verified' starts appearing as TRUE, letting the function resume.**

At the frontend, right after the user verify its email, the app does this:

```
const user = auth.currentUser;
user.reload().then(() => {
   console.log(user.emailVerified);
}
```

This logs as TRUE, but the 'context.auth.token.email_verified' inside Firebase Functions is FALSE.

I would like to know if there's a way to "force" a refresh of this 'context.auth.token' object in Functions, as the 'reload()' method does in the snippet above, so I can get the actual value of it, and not having to wait 2 minutes for it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing specific to Cloud Functions about this: the verification of the email address happens out of band (typically in your email app), and your application won't know about the change until it next refreshes the ID token for the user.

Getting a fresh ID token happens:

1. When the user signs in.
2. About 5 minutes before the existing token expires
   Since ID tokens are valid for an hour, this first happens about 55 minutes after the user signs in.
3. When you programmatically force a refresh by [calling `reload()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user#userreload) on the user object or [pass `true` to `getIdToken`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/auth.user#usergetidtoken).

Typically this means you'll want to force refresh the token after there's a reasonable chance that they verified, for example when your app regains focus or when they indicate that they've verified it themselves in your UI (you will have to build this). If you then call the Cloud Function after the refresh, it will be passed the up to date ID token with the updated verification status.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Frank. The 'reload()' method seems to refresh only the frontend user object, but the 'getIdToken(true)' worked fine. It refreshes also the token passed to the context in firebase functions